# Python Logging in Bottle not working in route

Tags: python, logging, routes, bottle

I am trying to use the Python logging library to log messages in my Bottle app. The logging works as expected outside the route, but my app is not logging anything in a route. Any idea what's wrong?

```
import logging

#logging
logger = logging.getLogger('myApp')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh = logging.FileHandler('log.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh) 

logger.info("Starting my application.") #this logs as expected

@route('/myRoute', method='POST')
def returnWord():
  userWord = (request.forms.get('submittedWord')).lower()
  # this doesn't log anything
  logger.info("testing logging inside route. word: %s" % (userWord))
  return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=userWord)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  daemon_run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: Are you sure your program is reaching the `logger.info` line?

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me.
You are probably getting an error before getting to the line

```
logger.info("testing logging inside route. word: %s" % (userWord))
```

Notice that you should see on your console the following line if your POST went well

> 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Aug/2016 19:20:15] "POST /myRoute HTTP/1.1" 200 20

To be sure you are own the right track add a simple function like this

```
@route('/testy', method='GET')
def testy():
    logger.info("testy is online :)")
    return "COOL"
```

Direct your web browser to localhost:8080/testy and see the COOL message.
Now you'll also see the log message in your file.